# OpenMP: How do I force one thread per iteration of a loop

Tags: openmp

I have a bunch of nested loops like the following

```
do k=1,5
   do i=1,10
   write(k_str, '(I0)') k
   conf_unit_single1=19+thread_num+i
   open(conf_unit_single1, file='positions_'//trim(adjustl(k_str))//&
                       '.dat', status='old')

   ! open i'th instance of file myfile.txt
   do j=1,100
      call read_config_mod(conf_unit_single1,configuration(:),iostat)                                                                                       
      end do
   end do
end do
```

I have tried to parallelize this in the following way
call omp_set_num_threads(10)

```
do k=1,5
!$omp parallel do num_threads(nunitcells) private(step) schedule(static,1)
   do i=1,10
      thread_num=omp_get_thread_num()

      write(k_str, '(I0)') k
      conf_unit_single1=19+thread_num+i
      open(conf_unit_single1, file='positions_'//trim(adjustl(k_str))//&
                           '.dat', status='old')

      ! open i'th instance of file myfile.txt
      do j=1,100
         call read_config_mod(conf_unit_single1,configuration(:),iostat)
         ! post-processing ...                                                                                       
      end do
   end do
   !$omp end parallel do                                                                                                                                                                                            

end do
```

But this still seems to mix up the assignment of threads to iterations of the loop over i and it ends up reading past EOF in a given file instance. I'm not very familiar with openMP and wondered if anyone would know what to do here?

Comment: Your question is unclear and we need to see more code, in particular how you open and read the file. That said, in what you are showing, the variable `j` should be declared as `private` in the OpenMP directive

Comment: Hi, thanks for your feedback. I've added some extra bits to the code that hopefully explains better what I'm trying to do. Please let me know if there is anything else I should clarify. I tried setting j to private but it doesn't appear to help unfortunately.

Comment: Privatizing `j` is non-optional if you want this code to work. `conf_unit_single1` should be private as well, and possibly `configuration` (depending on what `read_config_mod()` does).

Comment: Ah, thanks a lot. I see my misunderstanding  now. I think I took it for granted that the variables will have separate instances in different threads. I believe I should be able to solve the problem now by privatizing all necessary variables. I have a lot of them that I didn't show (additional loops etc). Is there a good way to privatize wholesale rather than have a whole bunch of explicit private variables in the directive?

Comment: You can use the `default(private)` clause, which makes all variables private, unless explicitely specified otherwise with the `shared` or `firstprivate`clauses. Alternatively you can enclose the code that is in the parallel code in some separared subroutine(s): the variables that are declared locally in the routine(s) are implicitely private

Comment: Hi, that's exactly what I was looking for - thanks a lot! Really appreciate the help with this. I don't seem to have the option of upvoting your comments or marking the question is closed; I guess my reputation is too low at the moment.